# AT&T Email Text Messaging Service Severly Truncating Messages

Tags: email, sms, att

When we send an email <10digitPhoneNumber>@txt.att.net we get the following result

```
FRM:<from email>
SUBJ: <subject>
MSG: <39 characters of the message>
```

It's always 39 regardless of the length of the email or the subject. Have other people seen this behavior before? Is there a work around? T-Mobile will place the message in an image if the content is over 160 characters, and we're not even close to that on AT&T. But our user is on AT&T so we have to use AT&T's email service, right? Or is there a 3rd party service we can use to email text messages.

The other work around I guess is to send text messages directly, we're using .NET, I haven't looked into this at all and would prefer not to manage this component.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: If you really care the email is being generated through Microsoft's Enterprise Library 6.0, however I can recreate the issue through simply sending an email in outlook.

Comment: Also we're using the same mechanism on a T-Mobile number / email address, and that works as expected

Comment: It doesn't seem applicable to this post as the code is simply an email message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that what was happening is the last two characters were getting chopped off some reason, so we appended three spaces to the message and now the whole message comes through clear. Weird.

Comment: thanks for that tip, that resolved the same problem I was having with AT&T